# `\def`, `\edef` math and commands

Tags: math-mode, macros, expansion

I have this command that's part of something bigger

```
\newcommand{\customParagraph}[2][1]{% Title, Name
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {\def \customParTitle{}}
        {\edef\customParTitle{ -- #1}}
    \edef\customParTitle{#2\customParTitle} % This can be used by other commands to populate ToC
    \subparagraph*{\customParTitle}
}
```

In my documents I call it like `\customParagraph{Proof}` or `\customParagraph[Proof of something]{Proof}` to get my subparagraphs. If I put some inline math in the first argument it's fine, but as soon as I put a command in there like `\customParagraph[Proof of something in $\R$]{Proof}`, where `\R` is defined as `\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}`, I get an *Undefined control sequence* error at the corresponding line. Putting `\mathbb{R}` directly gives the same result.

How can I fix this command to get the expected result? Keep in mind that the definition of `\customParTitle` can be used as below

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{\customParTitle}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the error?

Comment: As always on this site, you are more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example instead of just sniplets, then others can easily test your MWE

Comment: You’re right but I was in a hurry. I’ll add it asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a complete MWE I guess that it is caused by the multiple expansion of `\customParTitle`, so try changing the definition to the following (with this the arguments don't get expanded during the definition of `\customParTitle`):

```
\newcommand{\customParagraph}[2][1]{% Title, Name
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\def\customParTitle{}}
    {\def\customParTitle{ -- #1}}%
  \edef\customParTitle{\unexpanded{#2}\unexpanded\expandafter{\customParTitle}}% This can be used by other commands to populate ToC
  \subparagraph*{\customParTitle}%
}
```

Embedded in a self-created MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*\R{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand\customParagraph[2][1]
  {% Title, Name
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\customParTitle{}%
    \else
      \def\customParTitle{ -- #1}%
    \fi
    \edef\customParTitle
      {\unexpanded{#2}\unexpanded\expandafter{\customParTitle}}%
    \subparagraph*{\customParTitle}%
  }
\newcommand\YourCustomParagraph[2][1]
  {% Title, Name
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def \customParTitle{}%
    \else
      \edef\customParTitle{ -- #1}%
    \fi
    \edef\customParTitle{#2\customParTitle}%
    \subparagraph*{\customParTitle}%
  }

\begin{document}
\customParagraph[Proof of something in $\R$]{Proof}%
%\YourCustomParagraph[Proof of something in $\R$]{Proof}% doesn't work
\end{document}
```